# Html.Display, Raw not showing DateTime Converted to Local

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, datetime, razor

I have a List index view where one model value is an UTC timestamp. I've written code that checks to see if it's null, and if it's not outputs to the view the timestamp converted to a specified timezone. However, despite stepping through the debugger and the debugger hitting the Html.Raw.Display line and the variable showing a value of `{9/29/2015 2:23:10 PM}`, the td is empty

```
                <td>
                    @{
                        DateTime tmp;

                        //Check if not null, if not null convert to specified time zone
                        if (DateTime.TryParse(item.timestamp.ToString(), out tmp))
                        {
                            tmp = item.timestamp;
                            TimeZoneInfo cstZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central Standard Time");
                            DateTime cstTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(tmp, cstZone);

                            Html.Raw(cstTime.ToString() + " " + cstZone.StandardName); //Using Html.Display also fails
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.timestamp);
                        }
                    }
                </td>
```

What am I doing wrong here with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HtmlHelper.Raw` does not output content to the page it just returns a `IHtmlString` with Raw content.

What is causing confusion to you is that most of the time it's used with the Razor expression:

```
@Html.Raw(var)
```

This expressions is what makes the return of the function be output to the page, but in your example your are using it directly within a code block (`@{...}`).

Just add `@` before the call and it will work:

```
@Html.Raw(cstTime.ToString() + " " + cstZone.StandardName);
```